# Mock/patch function in view

Tags: python

```
from flask import request
from flask.views import MethodView
from unittest.mock import patch
from router.views.time_view import (
    _utcnow
)

class StateSetupView(MethodView):
    @app.route("/state-setup", methods=['POST'])
    def post():
        print(f"Non-mocked version: {_utcnow()}")
        with patch('router.views.time_view._utcnow', return_value = "LOL"):
            print(f"Mocked version: {_utcnow()}")
```

I can't seem to mock the function return value in runtime. The code above returns the same value in both instances. I do not want to wrap this in a pytest, this needs to work in a view.

Comment: You patch things where they're _used_, not where they're defined: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch. You seem to be mixing up test and implementation, though, so it's not clear what the right solution might be - what's the context?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So globally mocking a function return is not possible in python?

Comment: @jonrsharpe We have libraries using this "_utcnow" function here and there, I need to set it to a previous date so to speak (travel back in time). We don't have dependency injection for this specific value unfortunetly.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple replacing the function straight up worked.

```
router.views.time_view._utcnow = lambda: 12346789
```